# Conditional loading of tinymce editor based on the language

Tags: javascript, jsp, tinymce

**Environment**: JSP, tinyMCE editor

**Requirement:**
I have a page on which rich text editor has to displayed. If the language detected is french then french tinyMCE editor has to be displayed otherwise english.

I have initialized the the tinyMCE in 2 separate javascript files with 
language as "en" and "fr"
How can I conditionally include the javascript file in the same jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: [How I can add multi TinyMCE editors with different config for each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029077/how-i-can-add-multi-tinymce-editors-with-different-config-for-each-one)